# Zip Files in Subfolders Using WinZip

Tags: vba, winzip

When I use the shell command line to use winzip the variable r and q that return the path and file name doesn't recognize as a string when using the command line in vba.  Also what code would i Need to skip any zip files that are already in the directory.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ZipAll()
Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim colFiles As Scripting.File
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objStartFolder As String
Dim Subfolder As Scripting.Folder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "S:\UPSData\EOMOnHand\Abbott\"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
ShowSubFolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
End Function

Public Function ShowSubFolders(Folder)
Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim colFiles As Scripting.File
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objStartFolder As String
Dim Subfolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim r As String
Dim q As String
Dim NextRow As Long
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    NextRow = 1

    For Each Subfolder In Folder.Subfolders
    'MsgBox SubFolder.Path
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile In colFiles
    r = Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name & ".zip"
    q = Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name
    MsgBox r
    MsgBox q
    Shell "C:\Program Files\WinZip\WinZip64.exe -min -a " & r & " " & q
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next
Next
End Function
```

When I msgbox q i returns the s:\upsdata\eomonhands\abbott\abbott.xlsx.  I use thata as the file name in the command line that call winzip but it doesn't see it as a string.  How do I return q as a string.  Also what would be the code to filter out any further files in that folder that are already zip files.  I don't want to zip those.

Comment: You are definitely getting the syntax wrong in that command - `C:\Program Files\WinZip\WinZip64.exe -min -as:\UPSData\EOMOnHand\Abbott\xyz\abc.xlsxs:\UPSData\EOMOnHand\Abbott\xyz\*.xlsx` won't be valid because `-as:\UPSData\EOMOnHand\Abbott\xyz\abc.xlsxs:\UPSData\EOMOnHand\Abbott\xyz\*.xlsx` isn't a sensible parameter (but I don't have WinZip installed to check what the correct syntax is)

Comment: @YowE3K Ok Forget the winzip part.  When I get to the objfile.Name it says object required.  I re wrote the code to include the subolders path ok.  It won't display the name.

Comment: "It says Object Require when it hits the line ojbFile.Name", really?  The `For Each objFile in colFiles` should guarantee that it is populated!

Comment: Where are `r` and `q` defined?  Will you kindly add `Option Explicit` at top of code to force variable declaration?

Comment: Code (other than the WinZip issue) works for me.

Comment: @YowE3K I reposted the code with option explicit.  Now i defined r and q and the msgbox returns the full path and file name however winzip doesn't recognize it as a path or a string.  I can do it in dos prompt so I know the winzip command line I am using does work. Its like this `Shell "C:\Program Files\Winzip\winzip64.exe -min -a " S:\upsdata\eomonhand\abbott\abbott.xlsx.zip s:\upsdata\eomonhand\abbott\abbott.xlsx` Where r is the name of the zip file and q is the name of what i am zipping.  It does work in dos.  those are the exact parameters.

Comment: If you post (within the actual question so that we can read it correctly) the actual command that works in DOS it will be easy to tell you what is wrong, but without that I can't help.  Hopefully someone who has WinZip installed might help you.

Comment: @YowE3K Hi I apologize I am new a stack overflow.  I appreciate all your help.  I used Chr(34) before and after the variable and that allowed it to be seen as a string like it is in dos.

Comment: 10 months is not "new". (I've only been here 13 months, and it seems like a lifetime.)

Answer (score 0):

To zip all the files in the subfolders that are xlsx you can do the following:

```
Public Function ZipAll()
Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim colFiles As Scripting.Files
Dim objStartFolder As String
Dim Subfolder As Scripting.Folder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "S:\UPSData\EOMOnHand\Abbott\"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
ShowSubFolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
End Function

Public Function ShowSubFolders(Folder)
Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim colFiles As Scripting.Files
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objStartFolder As String
Dim Subfolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim FileName As String
Dim r As String
Dim q As String
Dim NextRow As Long
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    NextRow = 1

    For Each Subfolder In Folder.Subfolders
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile In colFiles
    FileName = Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name
    If Right(FileName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
    GoTo Line1
    Else
    GoTo Line2
    End If

Line1:
    r = Chr(34) & Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name & ".zip" & Chr(34)
    q = Chr(34) & Subfolder.Path & "\" & "*.xlsx" & Chr(34)
    iRunTaskID = Shell("C:\Program Files\WinZip\WinZip64.exe -min -a " & r & " " & q)
    DoEvents
    hProc = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, iRunTaskID)
    If hProc <> 0 Then
    WaitForSingleObject hProc, INFINITE
    CloseHandle hProc
End If
    r = Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name & ".zip"
    If Len(Dir$(r)) > 0 Then
    GoTo Line3
    Else
    GoTo Line2
    End If
Line3:
bfile = Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name
If Len(Dir$(bfile)) > 0 Then
 Kill bfile
End If
Line2:
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next
Next

End Function
```

Essentially if you put the filter on the filename it will jump to the line that zips the files and zips that file other than that it skips the other files that are listed.   If you use chr(34) in the winzp command line that allows it to be a string when called.